# Playing with an Array

Tags: math, numbers

Hi cant figure out solution for below problem (here is a link to the original problem: [Sumita and equal array](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/arrays/1-d/practice-problems/algorithm/sumit-and-equal-array/description/) 
). please help?

Sumita is playing with a Array A of size N. she wants to make all the values of A to be equal. she can multiply any number of the values in the array any number of times by X, Y and Z. Your task is to tell her whether she can do it or not. Print "She can" if she can do it else print "She can't" without ""

Input :

```
First line of the input will contain T (No. of test cases).
For each test case, first line will contain four space separated integers denoting N, X, Y and Z.
Then next line will contain N space separated integers of A
```

Output :

```
For every test case, print the required answer in a new line.
```

Constraints :

```
1 ≤ T ≤ 5
2 ≤ N ≤ 10^5
X, Y, Z ∈ {2, 3, 5, 7}
1 ≤ Ai ≤ 10^9
```

SAMPLE INPUT:

```
2
2 2 2 2
2 4
3 2 3 2
2 6 7
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
She can
She can't
```

Explanation:

```
Test case #1: Multiply first value by 2.
Test case #2: Not possible.
```

**My work so far:** I find out lcm of X,Y,Z if each element inside that array is divided or can divide by lcm then ans is she can else she can't

Comment: any element inside array can be multiplied by any number of time by X,Y,Z, and what i did i find out lcm of X,Y,Z if each element inside that array is divided or can divide by 30 then ans is she can else she can't

Comment: yes more then one elements can be multiplied

Comment: I have edited your question to include the information in your comments. Feel free to edit further if you like.

Comment: https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/arrays/1-d/practice-problems/algorithm/sumit-and-equal-array/description/

Comment: Above comment is the link to my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you give ideas of your own but no code, I will do the same: give some ideas but no code. If you try coding this idea and get stuck, edit your question by showing your code and ask for more help.

You have the right idea of finding the Least Common Multiple (LCM) of the numbers in the given array. For each element of the array, you then can calculate the quotient of the LCM and the element--this quotient is guaranteed to be a positive integer. Then see if there is any prime divisor of that quotient that is not X, Y, or Z. If there is such a divisor, then your task is not possible: "She can't". If there is no such divisor, then this element passes the test. If all elements pass this test, the task is possible: "She can".

For your first array `[2, 4]` and `X, Y, Z` values `[2, 2, 2]`, the array's LCM is `4`. The first quotient is `4 // 2 = 2`, the only prime divisor of that quotient is `2`, and that is in the list of `X, Y, Z`. The second quotient is `4 // 4 = 1`, which has no prime divisors, so that element also passes the test. All elements pass the test. so the task is possible.

For your second array `[2, 6, 7]` and `X, Y, Z` values `[2, 3, 2]`, the array's LCM is `42`. The first quotient is `42 // 2 = 21`, which has the prime divisors `3` and `7`. The first one (`3`) is in your list of `X, Y, Z`, but the last (`7`) is not, so the task is impossible. There is no need to check the quotients for the other elements of the array.

Can you program that? Note that I used Python's lists rather than arrays. Also note that this algorithm depends on the possible values of `X, Y, Z` being prime numbers--if they could be composite numbers, the algorithm would need to be adjusted and would be more complicated. To be more precise, the algorithm would need to be changed if any two possible values of `X, Y, Z` were distinct and were not relatively prime (had a Greatest Common Divisor greater than one).

Comment: yes i can , coding is not the issue, i applied lcm trick but not this modules trick. Can you explain me the logic behind it.

Comment: What do you mean by "modules trick"? My answer assumed that you know some number theory, which I asked in a comment (before I deleted it). If you do not know anything about prime numbers, you should learn some before attempting this problem. (That would include writing code to find the prime divisors of a number.) If you mean something more simple, clarify what you need to be explained.

Comment: I know about prime numbers. What i mean by modulo trick is that i did not notice that X,Y,Z are prime number. Note: I am an average student of maths.

Comment: @Prashank: I still do not understand what you want me to explain. And you are "an average student of maths" at what level (secondary school, college, etc,, and in which year) and in what country? Averages vary a great deal.

Comment: Nothing sir code worked thank you, i am looking into number theory a bit as suggested by you.